# Loopback: conditional value on upsert

Tags: loopback

so I am having this mass import of data to my DB and conditional whether a record exists or not I am inserting or updating (upsert)...

now, what I need is when it is inserting (new record) to populate the "created" property's value and 'modified' value with the current datetime... but only modified one when it is getting updated...

so if I would use operational hook of before save.... how do I know it is for an inserting record or for an updating record?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in different manner (would still be good to know the original answer)

in my case I upserted them all normaly with updated to current date, after, I find all with created:null and update just those with the created value.